# displaying my sql table result based on my radiobutton selection

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, radio-button

I have my radiobuttons as,

```
selection1:
field1<input type="radio" name="field1" value="field1"/>
field2<input type="radio" name="field2" value="field2"/>
field3<input type="radio" name="field3" value="field3"/>

selection2:
type1<input type="radio" name="type1" value="type1"/>
type2<input type="radio" name="type2" value="type2"/>
type3<input type="radio" name="type3" value="type3"/>
```

i have predefined values in my database table "test" as

```
field1   type1  10
field1   type2  20
field1   type3  30
field2   type1  30
field2   type2  50
field2   type3  60
field3   type1  80
field3   type2  90
field3   type3  100
```

if user selects `"field1"` and `"type1"` it should display the result as 10, if user selects `"field2"` and `"type3"`it should display 60, how can i do it in `php`, any ideas?, even small thought are welcome.

Comment: are radiobtn static?

Comment: That is a bit broad. What are you having problems with, the sql, php, etc.? And your form elements are missing names and values.

Comment: i can't able to get the datebase records depend on the two radiobuttons selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to use different name for different radio Button group

next if you want to use it in HTML form tag you can do some thing like below

```
<form action='test.php' method='post'>
selection1:
field1<input type="radio" name="field" value="field1"/>
field2<input type="radio" name="field" value="field2"/>
field3<input type="radio" name="field" value="field3"/>

selection2:
type1<input type="radio" name="type" value="type1"/>
type2<input type="radio" name="type" value="type2"/>
type3<input type="radio" name="type" value="type3"/>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

in PHP code you should use a function like this

```
function get_value($type,$field)
 {
 $sql="select result from test where field='$field' and type='$type'";
 $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 $result=mysql_fetch_array($query);
 return $result[result];
}

$field=$_POST['field'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
echo get_value($type,$field);
```

this will work for you

Comment: exactly what i am looking for.
still one more doubt, what if i have result2, result3 additionally in my database, how the code changes?

Comment: what you mean with result 2 and result 3 ?? you mean if i select field1 and type1 i have result 1 and result 2 and result 3???

Comment: 1- $sql="select result1,result2,result3 from test where field='$field' and type='$type'";
2- instead of return $result[result] use this  print_r($result)

Comment: Exactly.. Thanks for ur response, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Datatable GetRecord(string fieldName, string type)
{
  //Call Store Procedure and Pass fieldName , Type as param 
}

In you Store Procedure:

@FieldParam nvarchar(max),
@FieldType  nvarchar(max)
as 
begin
 select * from test where Field = @FieldParam and Type = @FieldType 
end
```